# How to calculate weighted average grade for numbers between 1 and 5?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The user can input his grades for several lectures. The inputfield allows numbers and letters (because there are lectures that arent graded, however, the user should be able to note that he passed the lecture).

I want to calculate and display the user his weigthed average grade based on the credits a lecture gives. The numbers are doubles.

```
public void CalculateAverageGrade()
{
    double gradeSum = 0;
    double creditsSum = 0;

    foreach (SemesterLecture semesterLecture in selectedSemester.semesterLectures)
    {
        try{
            double grade = Double.Parse(semesterLecture.grade) * semesterLecture.lecture.credits;
            gradeSum += grade;
            creditsSum += semesterLecture.lecture.credits;
        }
        catch (Exception e){}
    }

    if (Double.IsNaN(Math.Round((gradeSum / creditsSum), 1, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)))
    {
        semesterGrade.text = "-";
    }
    else
    {
        semesterGrade.text = Math.Round((gradeSum / creditsSum), 1, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) + "";
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you asking here? How to calculate a weighted average or how to display it?

Comment: I ask how to calculate the weighted average grade and only include numbers between 1 and 5. So when a user types in letters or a 6 it shouldnt be included. I tried several things. This is the code I currently have...

Comment: `if(value < 6) { do stuff }`?